# Error: Cannot set picklist values when a global picklist is referenced on the field

Tags: deployment, metadata-api

I'm trying to migrate an Obj with a field that has a Global ValueSet.

The Obj, the field, and the global valueset is listed and exported in the metadata but its giving me the next error when I try to push it to the destination org:

```
Error: Cannot set picklist values when a global picklist is referenced on the field
```

Comment: migrate global valueset and fields together

Comment: had to create the field and the global value set on the dest org before the metadata api deploy